# How can I extract the name of the selected file in TShellListView?

Tags: delphi, filenames

I've done a good search to see if anyone else has asked this question, it seems not. I find this pretty strange as it is easy to extract the path From TShellTreeView.Path and you get the fully qualified path.

However I tried as hard as I could looking through all the properties and methods of the class itself in the editor - no documentation - and the only likely string properties I could find where the captions for the tlistitems, which turn out to be blank. Also the 'selected' property turns out to be blank.

So the question is simply, how can I extract the name of any file - or files - that are selected in a TShellListView component. Also I do have the four Shell components linked and working, you can choose a drive, browse the directory structure, choose a mask and browse to the file you want.

TIA

Andrew

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you don't have activated the `MultiSelect` property check the `SelectedFolder.PathName` property, otherwise you can iterate over the Items and check the `Selected` property.

Try this

```
function GetSelectedFiles(ShellListView : TShellListView) : TStringList;
var
  Index : Integer;
begin
  Result:=TStringList.Create;
  if not ShellListView.MultiSelect then
    Result.Add(ShellListView.SelectedFolder.PathName)
  else
  for Index := 0 to ShellListView.Items.Count-1 do
    if ShellListView.Items[Index].Selected AND (not ShellListView.Folders[Index].IsFolder) then
      Result.Add(ShellListView.Folders[Index].PathName);
end;
```

Comment: Incidently, where can I find documentation for the tshelllistview, etc, components? Muscipula